# Does the connection and the command instances need to be re-used to get value out of the MySqlCommand.Prepare method

Tags: mysql, .net, postgresql

In the PostgreSQL .net connector it has some smarts about re-using the prepared logic of a command based on the fact that the connection will be pooled 
http://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html#persistency

> all prepared statements are persistent - they no longer get closed when a command or connection is closed. Npgsql keeps track of statements prepared on each physical connection; if you prepare the same SQL a second time on the same connection, Npgsql will simply reuse the prepared statement from the first preparation. This means that in an application with short-lived, pooled connections, prepared statements will gradually be created as the application warms up and the connections are first used. Then, opening a new pooled connection will return a physical connection that already has a prepared statement for your SQL, providing a very substantial performance boost.

However the MySql connector is ambiguous on this behavior

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html

So in the MySql .net connector does the MySqlCommand.Prepare only deliver value when used on the same instance of a command? Or does it have smarts under the covers in a similar way to the PostgreSQL .net connector